# Unable to run kotlinc-native command

Tags: kotlin, command-line-interface, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to run the [Kotlin/Native Hello Program](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-command-line-compiler.html#write-hello-kotlin-native-program)
but the terminal says the command `kotlin-native` cannot be found. I'm on a MacBook, using zsh (get same error when I use bash) and installed Kotlin via Homebrew before, so kotlin and it's compiler works on my machine, the `kotlinc` command works just fine. I'm trying to use the compiler instead of gradle for now. Is there a different command I'm supposed to be using?

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you may have had a similar problem to me. Installing `kotlin-native` via homebrew did not install the `kotlinc-native` command.

To get the command working, I had to do the following:

1. Go to https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases and get the latest version of Kotlin
2. Extract it to `.kotlin` in the home directory
3. Add `export PATH="$HOME/.kotlin/bin:$PATH"` to `.zshrc`

The problem with this method is that it's completely disconnected from Homebrew. You will have to run the steps again every time you want to update Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You've typed `kotlin-native` but the tutorial says `kotlinc-native`, which is the actual name of the process file.

If `kotlinc` works then you might just have a typeo.

I don't use these processes directly, but I'm somewhat familiar with them. My guess is check the name.